# Private API Nest.js

Tags: nestjs

I want to make a private Nest.js API so that no one can use it except the frontend and backend, but I don’t know how to do it correctly.  I tried 2 ways.  Method 1) IP whitelist.  When requesting, the IP is checked and if it is on the white list, then everything is fine, otherwise it will not be allowed through.  But what to do if the IP that needs to be skipped changes frequently?  2) I pass a special `apiKey` to headers that checks whether it is valid, but passing it to headers is dangerous, they can easily look at it.  How can I organize this correctly?

Comment: Did you check https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication (and maybe also https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authorization)?